# How can I make discord.Client in a class correctly and run as a task in my loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm working with Discord.py and I need to make discord.Client run in my own loop, because I want it to run multiple times (for more bots, so I don't have to make more and more files just so they run both at the same time).

This is the easiest example I could make:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

token = "token"

class Client(discord.Client):
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready():
        print(self.user.id)
    
    @commands.command()
    async def testing(ctx):
        await ctx.send("hello")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
client = Client(command_prefix="!")
loop.create_task(client.start(token))
loop.run_until_complete
```

It doesn't return anything at all; it just closes itself. I know I have errors there, but I don't know which and why. How can I fix them?

Comment: You don't use the event decorator for a command and you need to put the commands outside of the bot's definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're mixing discord.Client and commands.Bot/commands.Cog

```py
class Client(discord.Client):
```

should be

```py
class Client(commands.Cog):
```

And trying to run multiple bots by looping it is not going to go well. I intensely encourage you to just make multiple files.

Also, it should be:

```py
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Client(client))
```

If you're making it a cog, then you have to load it in another file.

If you just want a singular file then it should look like:

```py
class Client(commands.Bot):
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(self.user.id)

    @bot.command()
    async def testing(ctx):
        await ctx.send("hello")

client = Client(command_prefix="!")
client.run(token)
```